# What are the optimal Java Memory Settings for Railo 4.x / Tomcat 7?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, tomcat7, railo

I'm currently running Railo 4.0.4.001 final on an Amazon 64-bit Linux m1.medium cloud instance which has 3.75Gb of memory.

My `setenv.sh` script is currently starting Railo / Tomcat with ...

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m ";
```

My questions is this ... Can/should I use higher memory settings?  This machine is strictly an Apache/Tomcat/Railo web server with no other applications running.

Answer (score 0):

There is no global "optimal" settings for a JVM: it all depends on the nature of your application and its usage.

What you need to do is to profile your app and get an idea of how it uses memory, and configure it accordingly. This is a bit of a dark art (especially with CFML apps which tend to create far more class files than normal Java apps), and people base their careers on doing it, so "the rigth answer for you" bit outside the scope of a question on Server Fault.